# How to keep outer table from resizing when inner table is shown/hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In a webpage, when a button is click, a table hidden is shown within another table. However, each time, when the hidden table is toggled, the width of the outside table would resize itself. The fiddle demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/bEK8f/5/

I hope the initial width of the outer table would take into account of the size of the inner table. Therefore, the outer table width should not change by showing/hiding the inner table.

As cebirci showed below, fixing the width of the outer table and using the fixed layout would work. Note sure if the width of the outer table can be decided based on the hidden table. In this way, there is no need to manually set the outer table width.

Thank you very much!

I also include my code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#show").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#cat1').toggle();
    });

    $("#calculate").click(function(e){
        var diff = $('#diff').val();
        var sd = $('#sd').val();
        var effect = diff/sd;
        $('#es').val(effect.toFixed(2));
        $('#cat1').toggle();
    });
});

</script>

<style>
  table{border: 1px solid black;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table style="width:500px;table-layout: fixed;">
    <tr class="row2">
        <th class="col0">Effect size <button id="show">Show</button></th><td class="col1"><input type="text" id="es" value="0.1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cat1" id='cat1'  style="display:none">
        <th class="col0" id='test'></th>
        <td class="col1">
        <table>
            <tr><th class="col0 centeralign" colspan="2"> Effect size calculation </th></tr>
            <tr><td>Difference</td> <td> <input type="text" id="diff" value=".1"> </td></tr>
            <tr><td>sd</td> <td> <input type="text" id="sd" value="1"> </td></tr>
            <tr><td></td> <td> <button  id="calculate">Calculate</button> </td></tr>
        </table>        
        </td>
    </tr>   
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `th` tag for only header row of your table. In your table using `td` is better because you dont have any header row for titles etc..
In your html, your new table is appearing in a cell, and the cell is small for your table so it resizes. You can use `colspan` for merging two cells of your second row.

Your html code can be like that:

```
<table style="width:340px;table-layout: fixed;">
    <tr class="row2">
        <td class="col0">Effect size <button id="show">Show</button></td>
        <td class="col1"><input type="text" id="es" value="0.1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cat1" id='cat1'  style="display:none">

        <td class="col1" colspan="2">
        <div style="display:inline"><table style="width:100%">
            <tr><th class="col0 centeralign" colspan="2"> Effect size calculation </th></tr>
            <tr><td>Difference</td> <td> <input type="text" id="diff" value=".1" /> </td></tr>
            <tr><td>sd</td> <td> <input type="text" id="sd" value="1" /> </td></tr>
            <tr><td></td> <td> <button  id="calculate">Calculate</button> </td></tr>
        </table></div>      
        </td>
    </tr>   
</table>
```

And jsfiddle link is http://jsfiddle.net/bEK8f/2/

Comment: Thank for your reply. This is just a small part of a big table. In the jsfiddle you provided, if the hidden table is wider than the cell of the outside table, it would still adjust the size of the outside table. See http://jsfiddle.net/bEK8f/4/. Thanks again.

Comment: what should it be, if hidden table is wider? It may be better, if you describe your goal clearly or share a sketch drawing etc.

Comment: I want to keep the size of the outer table when show or hide the inner one (the initial size would take into account the size of the inner) . I noticed the question was edited and that is what I want. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the code. Some css properties were added to both tables. I fixed the width of outer table and set its layout as fixed. And width of inner table is set to 100%. I hope they solves your pproblem.

Comment: Yes, fixed the outer table width worked. Thanks. Originally, I had hoped the outer table width can be set based on the inner table width through javascript. But this might not worth the effort.